# In an AppDelegate, how is the main UIWindow instantiated?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

A snippet of the default code in a Master-Detail Xcode project

---

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
 UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;  // *** here ***
    MasterViewController *controller = (MasterViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
    controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    return YES;
}
```

AppDelegate.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
```

I am aware that @synthesize just sets the accessor methods, and no initialization happens automagically. But how does `window` have a non-nil `rootViewController` if it is never explicitly initialized? Is this just Xcode init'ing behind the scenes?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From [my book](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch14.html#_the_window):

> If you choose the Storyboard option as you specify a template, the process works a little differently. The app is given a main storyboard, pointed to by the Info.plist key “Main storyboard file base name” (`UIMainStoryboardFile`). After `UIApplicationMain` instantiates the app delegate class, it asks the app delegate for the value of its `window` property; if that value is nil, the window is created and assigned to the app delegate’s `window` property. The storyboard’s initial view controller is then instantiated and assigned to the window’s `rootViewController` property, with the result that its view is placed in the window as its root view; the window is then sent the `makeKeyAndVisible` message. All of that is done behind the scenes by `UIApplicationMain`, with no visible code whatever. That is why, in a storyboard template, the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` implementation is empty.

Comment: This answers very well who updates the window property, but see my answer below for how it is done.

Comment: For me, `UIMainStoryboardFile` is different from `NSMainStoryboardFile`. I specified the latter, so I get no window.

Comment: @DawnSong As often happens, NS is for AppKit and MacOS, while UI is for UIKit and iOS.

Comment: @matt However, Xcode displays "Main storyboard file base name" for both, which is really confusing. I tried to paste `UIMainStoryboardFile` blankly, and it worked like a miracle. I found the cause until previewing codes diff when committing. I should have open "Quick Help Inspector" or shown "Raw Keys & Values".

Answer (score 4):

From the [`UIWindow` documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html):

> Note: When you use storyboards and the Xcode app templates to create an app, a window is created for you.

If you don't use storyboards, the window is explicitly created, though all the standard project templates do this out of the box. You'll see a line similar to this in the app delegate:

```
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
```

Using storyboards, the window is created behind the scenes when the main storyboard is loaded (see the [View Controller Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/index.html) for more info).

Answer (score 2):

From Apple's docs (in "Using View Controllers in Your App"):

> The Main Storyboard Initializes Your App’s User Interface
>
> The main storyboard is defined in the app’s Information property list file. If a main storyboard is declared in this file, then when your app launches, iOS performs the following steps:
>
> It instantiates a window for you.
>   It loads the main storyboard and instantiates its initial view controller.
>   It assigns the new view controller to the window’s rootViewController property and then makes the window visible on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

The above answers only who sets the window variable without answering the main questions: "But how does window have a non-nil rootViewController if it is never explicitly initialized? Is this just Xcode init'ing behind the scenes?" and seem to suggest that there is magic afoot. Not a satisfactory answer for me, and so with a little digging, all becomes clear.

The generated code defines AppDelegate as

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
     ...
}
```

When you search the project, there is no other reference to window, so apparently it should remain nil, but actually is set to the correct value (by the methods outlined above). The "magic" is that AppDelegate conforms to the UIApplicationDelegate which includes an declaration:

```
    optional public var window: UIWindow? { get set }
```

Part of conforming to the UIApplicationDelegate is the redeclaration of the public variable *window*. When the underlying Application references the variable *window* in the protocol, it is actually linked to the variable *window* in our class. When the calling Application updates that variable *window* in the protocol, it is actually updating our variable *window*. So when we need to access the value in our program it is ready and waiting.

This is **not** Xcode magic, but an integral part of the Swift language. When using protocols we can employ the same techniques in our own Swift programs. This is just the same as our implementations of various functions in our classes which we do all the time: e.g. UIApplicationDelegate defines

`optional public func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication)`

so we can write our own implementation which is then "magically" called!

For completeness, note the **@UIApplicationMain** tag on the class. This defines the entry point for the application and is what makes everything work together. The actual class name is irrelevant, and can be given any name you require, as long as it is of type UIResponder and conforms to the UIApplicationDelegate.

Answer (score 1):

In your Storyboard, there is a little arrow you can drag around:

[image: arrow]

If you were using xibs/nibs instead, the 'Main Interface' field would be filled out.

[image: interface]

In the end, yep, it's iOS/Xcode magic.

Comment: Nothing "magic" about it. This is not a good thing to tell a questioner!

Comment: If that's not magic then nothing is. It's no secret that everything breaks down to an assembly instruction, but if a graphical arrow signifies that code is compiled without me writing it (or viewing it), I think it's safe to call that magic.

Comment: That arrow is there because you have designated this view controller as the initial view controller. All that arrow does is provide a further indication of that fact. The runtime calls `instantiateInitialViewController` - which is right there in the UIStoryboard documentation. Still no magic.