# Create UIApplicationDelegate class at runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-runtime

Using the Objective C runtime, I am trying to create an AppDelegate for my iOS app at runtime. This is just for research purposes, I have no intent to ship this.

My steps so far are:

- Create a class at runtime called `AppDelegate`.
- Add an instance variable called `_window`.
- Add a property called `window` that uses the instance variable as a backing variable and use two C functions as getters and setters.
- Add a method for the selector `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` with an implementation in C that returns `YES`. At this point, the class implements the `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol.
- Register the class with the runtime.

However, when I launch the program on a connected iPhone, the screen stays black, despite the program actually not crashing. The debugger shows that my implementations get called. Following the documentation, the OS first checks if my `window` property is `nil` (which it is), then creates a UIWindow itself and uses my setter to assign the UIWindow to my delegate instance.

When I access this window, it seems fully functional: It has the usual bounds (NSRect: Height = 667; Width = 375; X = 0; Y = 0;) and my custom ViewController gets initiated, `viewDidLoad` is called.

Can anybody help me to find out why the screen stays black, though?

Calls to `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible]` don't work, the screen stays black. If I create a window myself in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and assign the rootViewController of the previous `UIWindow`, that works. So it's definitely the UIWindow in my delegate that's somehow broken.

Here is the code I am using:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>
#import <stdio.h>


id getter(id self, SEL _cmd) {
    Ivar ivar = class_getInstanceVariable(objc_getClass("AppDelegate"), "_window");
    id var = object_getIvar(self, ivar);
    printf("is nil: %s\n", var == nil ? "true" : "false");
    if (var != nil) {
        printf("%s\n", [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", CGRectCreateDictionaryRepresentation(((UIWindow *) var).bounds)] UTF8String]);
    }
    return object_getIvar(self, ivar);
}

void setter(id self, SEL _cmd, id new) {
    printf("setter...\n");
    Ivar ivar = class_getInstanceVariable(objc_getClass("AppDelegate"), "_window");
    object_setIvar(self, ivar, new);
}

BOOL didFinishLaunching(id self, SEL _cmd, id launchOptions) {
    printf("didFinishLaunching called\n");
    return YES;
}


int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        Class delegate = objc_allocateClassPair([NSObject class], "AppDelegate", 0);
        class_addIvar(delegate, "_window", sizeof(UIWindow *), rint(log2(sizeof(UIWindow *))), @encode(UIWindow *));

        objc_property_attribute_t type = { "T", "@\"UIWindow\"" };
        objc_property_attribute_t strength = { "&", "" };
        objc_property_attribute_t atomic = { "N", "" };
        objc_property_attribute_t backingVar = { "V", "_window" };
        objc_property_attribute_t attrs[] = { type, strength, atomic, backingVar };
        class_addProperty(delegate, "window", attrs, 4);

        class_addMethod(delegate, @selector(window), (IMP) getter, "@@:");

        class_addMethod(delegate, @selector(setWindow:), (IMP) setter, "v@:@");

        class_addMethod(delegate, @selector(application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:),
                        (IMP) didFinishLaunching, "B@:@");
        objc_registerClassPair(delegate);

        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");
    }
}
```

And this is the stdout output:

```
is nil: true
setter...
didFinishLaunching called
is nil: false
{
    Height = 667;
    Width = 375;
    X = 0;
    Y = 0;
}
is nil: false
{
    Height = 667;
    Width = 375;
    X = 0;
    Y = 0;
}
ViewController.viewDidLoad() called
is nil: false
{
    Height = 667;
    Width = 375;
    X = 0;
    Y = 0;
}
```

Comment: Where's the code that actually creates the window and view controller? That's all normally done in the `didFinishLaunching` method.

Comment: Not with storyboards. The UIApplication retrieves the delegate's window property and if it is nil, creates a window by itself and sets it to that property. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16446971/4351927

Comment: You said nothing about using storyboards.

Comment: I didn't think it was part of the question. I'm trying to create the AppDelegate that is part of every iOS application template at runtime. When I use the code from the templates, the app works fine, but when I create the class at runtime, the screen stays black. This only affects main.c, AppDelegate.h and AppDelegate.m, which I am trying to get rid of. The rest is just Xcode's template project.

Comment: "B@:@" should be "b@:@", but also, the whole function is wrong. I'd say you should have "b@:@@" with the method defined as BOOL didFinishLaunching(id self, SEL _cmd, id application, id options);

Comment: The topic is over 2 years old. Apart from that, I accepted an answer with an implementation that actually worked, and dismissing that with "the whole function is wrong" isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue: ARC was releasing my UIWindow.

Changing the setter to

```
void setter(id self, SEL _cmd, id new) {
    Ivar ivar = class_getInstanceVariable(object_getClass(self), "_window");
    id old = object_getIvar(self, ivar);
    if (![old isEqual: new]) {
        if(old != nil) {
            objc_msgSend(old, sel_getUid("release"));
        }
        object_setIvar(self, ivar, new);
        objc_msgSend(new, sel_getUid("retain"));
    }
}
```

fixes this.